# Find facebook local currency callback

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-php-sdk, payment

While integrating local currency to my app, I have a small issue understanding how to use the callback.

Basically what I am looking for is the part of the code responsible for the database updates. The place where the payment is confirmed.

Here is the code:

```
$app_secret = '';

// Validate request is from Facebook and parse contents for use.
$request = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request'], $app_secret);

// Get request type.
$request_type = $_POST['method'];

// Setup response.
$response = '';

if ($request == null) {
// handle an unauthenticated request here
}

if ($request_type == 'payments_get_item_price') {
// Retrieving the user's info
$user_currency = $request['payment']['user_currency'];
$user_country = $request['user']['country'];

// Here we verify the product by passing back the URL of the OG product
$item['product'] = $request['payment']['product'];

// This is the quantity passed from the JS call to render the pay dialog.
// This parameter is optional and defaults to 1.
$quantity = $request['payment']['quantity'];

// Based on the user's currency and country, we set the price.
// We use fixed values here for testing.
  switch($user_currency) {
  case 'EUR':
      $item['amount'] = 2.99;
      $item['currency'] = 'EUR';
      break;
      case 'GBP':
      $item['amount'] = 2.49;
    $item['currency'] = 'GBP';
    break;
case 'BRL':
    $item['amount'] = 6.99;
    $item['currency'] = 'BRL';
    break;
// Here we default to USD. If a user's preferred currency is different than one
// that you specify, we will convert from the developer provided currency
// and amount to a new amount in the user's currency. You can choose whatever
// default currency works best for you.
default:
    $item['amount'] = 3.99;
    $item['currency'] = 'USD';
    break;
 }

 // Optionally, you may also choose to override the quantity_min / quantity_max values
  // which were passed in when invoking the Pay Dialog.
   $item['quantity_min'] = 1;
  $item['quantity_max'] = 100;

  // Optionally, it's also possible to override the OG product object's title, 
  // plural_title and description.
  $item['title'] = 'Override Title';
  $item['plural_title'] = 'Override Title Plural';
  $item['description'] = 'Override Description';

  // Finally we add the item information to the response 'content'
  $response['content'] = $item;
}

// Return the identical method
$response['method'] = $request_type;

// Send data back
echo json_encode($response);

// You can find the following functions and more details
// on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

  // Decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check signature
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
return null;
  }
  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Facebook will return the order_id of an order client-side once completed, and with that you may use the graph api to check the order, and perform your update.

The other solution is "Real time updates", which i havent quite understood yet.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the call back url in your app settings first, `yourdomain.com/mycallback.php` when a purchase is made or cancelled Facebook will **POST** to that page.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/

```
$request_type = $_POST['method'];  // catches the post from facebook with purchase info.
```

Comment: This is not true since in static payment in the local currency the call back url is not being call from facebook anymore, only on dynamic pricing it will use your callback url.

Comment: I will update my answer to reflect the up and coming changes for payments, but you can disable that change in app settings still..